# PHP, Javascript and url variable issues

Tags: php, javascript

I have two files......

a.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var randomnumber=new Array(); 

for(var i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
   randomnumber[i]=Math.random();
}

document.getElementById("h_field").value = randomnumber[1];

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myform" action="process.php?var1=h_field"  method="GET" >
    <input type="hidden" id ="h_field">
    <input type="Submit" value="my button">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

b.php

```
<?
echo $_GET['var1'];
?>
```

What i plan to do is to use the JavaScript to create an array of random numbers.
Then place the first element of this array in the hidden field whose id is `h_field`.
Then create a url variable and assign the value of the hidden field to that variable.  And Finally `$_GET` it, and print it to the screen with the page that will process the form.

Problem

1. The outcome is just a white page.
2. I cannot see the url variable in the address bar of the processing page either.

Comment: Just define your "action" property for the form as action="process.php" and use name="h_field" inside the input tag. All names will be automatically converted and passed as GET parameters. You'll get $_GET['h_field']

Comment: Happy Coding To You As Well!!!!!

Comment: The accepted answer won't work (it will, but doesn't answer your question, you'll get issues anyway). The answer given by Snippet is more accurate. You should change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your script located in `<head></head>` section, it will be executed immediately, before `<body></body>` section loaded: `<input type="hidden" id ="h_field">` might not even exist in this moment.

1. Move `<script></script>` section to the `<body></body>` section after `<form></form>` declaration.
2. Other way is convert script to a function and assign it as an event handler for `window.onload`.
3. If you want to submit your value to the server, you should supply `name` attribute to the input field, as **@DevZer0** mentioned.

Fixed script:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function init(){
    var randomnumber = []; 

    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        randomnumber[i] = Math.random();
    }

    document.getElementById("h_field").value = randomnumber[1];
}

window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="myform" action="process.php?var1=h_field"  method="GET" >
    <input type="hidden" name="h_field" id="h_field">
    <input type="Submit" value="my button">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move the body section after form declaration? you must be joking? you mean to say move the script section i am sure

Comment: @DevZer0 made more obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your hidden input needs a `name` attribute

```
<input type="hidden" id ="h_field" name="h_field" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why create a new variable. GET will automatically add all the input inside the form as GET variables. so you can use it like this

```
<form id="myform" action="b.php"  method="GET" >
    <input type="hidden" id ="h_field" name="h_field">
    <input type="Submit" value="my button">
</form>
```

You can get the values from h_field like so: `$_GET['h_field'];`

also your javascript code run before the html was loaded so you will get an error `Cannot set property 'value' of null` on you javascript code.

Here is a complete code

***a.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<script> 

function LoadArray(){
    var randomnumber=new Array(); 

    for(var i=0; i<=10; i++)
    {
       randomnumber[i]=Math.random(); 
    } 
    document.getElementById("h_field").value = randomnumber[0];
}
 window.onload = LoadArray;
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <form id="myform" action="b.php"  method="GET" >
        <input type="hidden" id ="h_field" name="h_field">
        <input type="Submit" value="my button">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and on your **b.php** always put php when creating a php tags`<?php ?>`

***b.php***

```
<?php
echo $_GET['h_field'];
?>
```